# Some problem with NumberFormatter

Tags: objective-c, delegates, nsnumberformatter

```
 -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField == self.nameField)
    {
        self.movie.name = self.nameField.text;
    }
    else if(textField == self.summaryField)
    {
        self.movie.summary = self.summaryField.text;
    }
    else if(textField == self.budgetField)
    {
        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
        [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
        self.movie.budget = [formatter numberFromString:self.budgetField.text];
        NSLog(@"%@",self.movie.budget);
        [formatter release];
    }
}
```

The Above code is from the Movie_LibraryEditorViewController.m file which is my second view in my project. In ***"self.movie.budget" it doesn't take the value, it takes as null.***
In the First View i have labels in which the text is displayed.
Now "movie" object is of the class Movie_Library in which i have overridden the following method.

> 

```
-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)newname budget:(NSNumber *)newbudget summary:(NSString *)newsummary
    {
        self = [super init];
        if(nil!=self)
        {
            self.name = newname;
            self.budget = newbudget;
            self.summary = newsummary;
        }
        return self;
    }
```

Now my question is ***Why the Null value? Am i doing smmin wrong here?***

Comment: Just to summarize the above, My question is : In "self.movie.name" where movie is the object of class Movie_Library and name is a NSString type, why is the value taken as (null)? am i using the NSNumberFormatter in a wrong way? Ne Help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: issue might relate to the formatting of input string in the field from UI. are there any checks that user is entering proper value?

Comment: What @samfisher said. Please give some examples of the values that have been entered into the text field which give null values.

Comment: NSLog self.budgetField.text and post the result.

Comment: the user can enter any number, "budget" is a NSNumber type, say suppose the user enters 42185 then on my first view where i have labels it will be displayed as $42185 since i have used "NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle". No matter what number the user enters The value of self.movie.budget is "(null)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to type the currency code if you use `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle`. Default code is "$". So, the string should look like this

```
[formatter numberFromString:@"$34"];
```

Comment: i didn't quite understand you there, do u mean that i should rewrite it as > self.movie.budget = [formatter numberFromString:@"$%@",self.budgetField.text];<br> is that what u are suggesting?

Comment: It depends what string you are expecting to have from the text field. If user does not type $ character, which is possible, you may need to add it to the string before passing it to the formatter. Otherwise, the result will be nil. In other words, you always need to make sure the currency symbol is in the string.

Comment: Bingo! that was it! Thanks dude, i din noe that u need to append the default currency char before passing it to the formatter. Thanks a lot. It really helped.